# Macro exports the first row only

Tags: excel, vba

i wrote a macro for CSV to excel import for more then 65 k rows. I invoke the macro from c# through a button click.In the macro i wrote the code to read the text file line by line and add to the coloumn. Finally i select the whole coloumn and export to excel using enable "Text to coloumns" by comma seperated.

> The problem is , it exports the first row only.

kindly help me.

```
Sub Read(FileName As String)
 'Dimension Variables
      Dim ResultStr As String
      'Dim FileName As String
      Dim FileNum As Integer
      Dim Counter As Double
      'Ask User for File's Name
      'FileName = InputBox("Please enter the Text File's name, e.g. test.txt")
      'Check for no entry
      If FileName = "" Then End
      'Get Next Available File Handle Number
      FileNum = FreeFile()
      'Open Text File For Input
      Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
      'Turn Screen Updating Off
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      'Create A New WorkBook With One Worksheet In It
      Workbooks.Add template:=xlWorksheet
      'Set The Counter to 1
      Counter = 1
      'Loop Until the End Of File Is Reached
      Do While Seek(FileNum) <= LOF(FileNum)
         'Display Importing Row Number On Status Bar
          Application.StatusBar = "Importing Row " & _
             Counter & " of text file " & FileName
          'Store One Line Of Text From File To Variable
          Line Input #FileNum, ResultStr
          'Store Variable Data Into Active Cell
          If Left(ResultStr, 1) = "=" Then
             ActiveCell.Value = "'" & ResultStr
          Else
             ActiveCell.Value = ResultStr
          End If

          'For xl97 and later change 16384 to 65536
          If ActiveCell.Row = 65536 Then
                ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Select
                Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=False, Comma:=True
                'If On The Last Row Then Add A New Sheet
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
          Else
             'If Not The Last Row Then Go One Cell Down
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
          End If
          'Increment the Counter By 1
          Counter = Counter + 1
      'Start Again At Top Of 'Do While' Statement
      Loop
      'Close The Open Text File
      Close
      ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Select
      Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=False, Comma:=True
      'Remove Message From Status Bar
      Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

C sharp Button click event,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            file_Writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\tstf.csv",true);
            //file_Writer.Close();
            //first row
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                file_Writer.Write("A,");
            }
            file_Writer.Write("\n");


            // second row

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                file_Writer.Write("B,");
            }

            file_Writer.Close();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);


            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Excel.ApplicationClass oExcel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            oExcel.Visible = true;
            Excel.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
            Excel._Workbook oBook = null;
            oBook = oBooks.Open("F:\\read.xls", oMissing, oMissing,
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

            // Run the macros.
            //RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[] { "DoKbTest" });
            RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[] { "siva1", @"c:\tstf.csv" });


            // Quit Excel and clean up.
            oBook.Close(false, oMissing, oMissing);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook);
            oBook = null;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks);
            oBooks = null;
            oExcel.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
            oExcel = null;


            GC.Collect();
        }
```

Comment: Does it work when invoked from Excel ?

Comment: No it doesn't work invoked on excel also

Comment: Then it is not a c# problem. I removed that tag.

Comment: Thank for reply. If I directly open the text file and edit any charecter and save file which one created through c# , workin fine. What could ne the problem?

Comment: did you check the items I mentionned in my answer below ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of problem . This is due to carriage return "\n". I add the "\r\n" at the end of line instead of "\n" only.

```
file_Writer.Write("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Either your `Do While` condition is not working as you expect. Try:

```
Do until Eof(FileNum)
   ....
Loop
```

And/Or the problem is due to the fact you do not properly close your output file. Try:
`Close Filenum`